Geometric interpretation of the solution of object and constraint function partial derivatives
For optimizing an object function $f(x,y)$ subject to a constraint function $g(x,y)$ we solve an Euler-Lagrange multiplier linked partial derivatives relation
$$ \frac{f_x(x,y)}{g_x(x,y)}= \frac{f_y(x,y)}{g_y(x,y)}$$
If we obtain the solution as $h(x,y), $ then how are functions $ f,g,h $ or their intersections geometrically interpreted among them  in 3d?
In a simple example the two variable $x,y$ functions are
$$ (f,g,h)=(x-4y,~x^2+2y^2=3,~y+2x=0). ~$$
Thanks, also for including any illustrative Monge plots.
